# Use text or image link to play/pause WordPress audio embed

Tags: php, wordpress, audio, toggle

I'm using the wp_audio_shortcode to pull podcast audio into WordPress posts. The mejs-element player is working just fine, but what I want is to play the audio by clicking on a thumbnail of the podcast or playhead icon.

Here's what's happening inside the loop:

```
<div class="play-icon-large">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/play-icon-big.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<img src="<?php echo catch_that_image($loop->ID) ?>" alt="" />
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
if (preg_match('/http:\/\/traffic.libsyn.com(.*)$/m', $content,$matches)) { ?>
    <div class="header-audio-player"> 
    <?php $trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$matches); ?>
    <?php $attr = array(
        'src'      => $trimmed_array[0],
        'loop'     => '',
        'autoplay' => '',
        'preload'  => 'none'
    );
    echo wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );
    } ?>
    </div>
```

Any ideas?